# Is it correct to say the interval of real numbers from 0 to 1 is more dense than that from 0 to n?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

If the cardinality of the set of real numbers in the interval $[0, 1]$ is $c$, and the cardinality of another set of real numbers, say those in the interval $[0, n]$ where $n>1$ is also $c$, then is it correct to say that the first interval must be more dense than the second?

Comment: No.  The two sets are in one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: I would agree with Matthew. What is your definition of “density”?

Comment: This question is not really well-defined because density is a property of a subset in a topological space. The question is about a set being dense as a property of a set, without saying in which space we are viewing the set.

Comment: If one defines a uniform probability density on both those intervals, the probability of a random selection being in any sub-interval of width $\epsilon$ is lower in the case of $[0,n]$.  But doing so requires a lot more mathematical machinery than elementary set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I fail to see how this is a duplicate. The asker explicitly stated that they already know that there are equally many elements in the two sets. This is not about counting the elements. I do agree that the question might need some work, but closing it as a duplicate is wrong in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you. As a beginner I had no strict definition of "dense". Thank you for your helpful comments.

Comment: @Arthur: You are correct, and this is definitely my fault. But it seems that the OP is not entirely sure what they mean when they say "dense". Which may or may not imply it has to do with cardinality rather than any topological or order-related definition. So until this is clarified to a meaningful question, I'm reluctant to reopen this again. I mean, even your first instinct was to post an answer which talked about cardinality.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang That's answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would say that all my answer said about cardinality was an acknowledgment that the asker was correct about it. I didn't really use the cardinality as such. At any rate, it's a moot point, since I thought the answer was bad and deleted it.

Comment: R is more dense than Q.